# Firefox eats my text

Tags: html, css, firefox

I really needs your help. I can not beat a bug in a Firefox browser (current version is 45.0). Under certain unknown conditions, part of the text block is lost.

To understand it, check out the following snippet in Firefox and Chrome browser.

```css
.fluid {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.price {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #454545;
}
.valuta {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #161616;
}
.amount {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #161616;
}
.align {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.center-block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix::after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is an example especially for comparison of Firefox browser display it in other browsers. The amount field is not displayed correctly in Firefox free browser, with a portion of the text is lost -->

<!-- Short amount example -->
<div class="fluid">
  <div class="center-block">
    <div class="align clearfix">
      <div class="price">Price:</div>
      <div class="valuta">$</div>
      <div class="amount">25 600</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Long amount example -->
<div class="fluid">
  <div class="center-block">
    <div class="align clearfix">
      <div class="price">Price:</div>
      <div class="valuta">$</div>
      <div class="amount">25 600 25 600 25 600 25 600 25 600 25 600 25 600 25 600</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Long amount without spaces example -->
<div class="fluid">
  <div class="center-block">
    <div class="align clearfix">
      <div class="price">Price:</div>
      <div class="valuta">$</div>
      <div class="amount">1234567890000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cool! As you can see with Firefox in "short amount example" - There are no numbers =(. But Chrome working fine! =)

Please help me to fix it!

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `.amount` class to

```
.amount {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #161616;
    max-width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

You need to specify width for ellipsis to work and also all the floats need to specified.

See working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xorL7t0n/4/)

Comment: I can do this without having to manually calculate the maximum width, like in Chrome browser?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Google Chrome adjusts many properties by itself(for example `float:left` in your case) but Firefox does not assume values. You don't have to calculate max-width. Set some upper limit and you should be good